# Glue used to adhere cellphone / laptop components (not screen)

Tags: repair, mechanical-assembly, adhesives

What type of glue is used to adhere cellphone (or laptop) components (excluding the screen which has its own speciality glue)? I'm talking about the sticky, but not too sticky glue used to hold things like the antennas, nfc flex, camera, battery etc. in place... when a firm but non-permanent hold is desired.

It seems to be a super thin double sided tape? What is it called and where can it be bought? (Searching phone glue yields just the very strong ones for the screen.)

I suspect it's not a fancy type of adhesive...

Some example images from [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Samsung+Galaxy+S8+Teardown/87136):

[image]
[image]

Comment: 3M makes the 2x sided adhesive tape

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt a search on Amazon for 3M double sided tape yields a large variety... what is the specific kind used in this instance?

Comment: Supplier/distributor preference for each application depends on thickness , temp range and if thermal conductivity sand serviceability is important

Comment: True, but looking for a general good enough substitute to hold items in place. What I am finding is either too strong(permanent) or too thick.

Comment: I use subfloor PL400 low VOC polyurethane in very thin amount or dots with a toothpick from. Large cheap tube. For thin flex , I might consider liquid rubber cement intended for paper, and consult with Loctite for commercial equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research based on @tony-stewart-older-than-dirt's comment and found [this section on the 3M website](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/All-3M-Products/Electronics/Electronics-Materials/Electronic-Assembly-Tapes/Double-Sided-Tapes/?N=5002385+8709318+8710652+8711017+8734572+8734637+3294857497&rt=r3) dedicated to adhesives for electronics assembly. However, they [seem a bit high](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQt07gEDVhU) on the strength end...

[image]